# Czech Residency and Re-entering Schengen

Tags: schengen, residency, czech-republic

I am a Canadian living in the Czech Republic on a study visa. I have lived there since September 2018. I renewed my visa in late 2019, and it was approved. However, I could only make the document collection appointment for January 2020. I went home to Canada for Christmas. I had not left the Schengen zone since I moved there in 2018. Since I do not have the supporting physical document of my residency, will the Schengen border guards (Frankfurt) give me trouble? Can they see my residency status in their system? Or should I just do what everybody else does and just say I'm visiting friends?

Comment: Never lie to a border agent. Tell your document will be waiting for you to collect it.